# Create dataframe serie from the prediction of a neural network

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am using a neural network. When I try to compare the predictions with the real values from the test set, I cannot do it because it does not let me create a dataframe with the predictions. So basicly I am not able to get test_predictions.shape = (10092,) instead o (10092,1). This "1" is causing me all the troubles. Can somebody help?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.7, random_state=101)
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss = 'mse')


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=25, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)

test_predictions = model.predict(X_test)

y_test = pd.Series(y_test)
test_predictions = pd.Series(test_predictions)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test_predictions = np.squeeze(test_predictions) should do the trick, it collapses all dimensions that have just one Element